# Possibly Möbius Inversion Formula Application

Tags: number-theory, mobius-inversion

**EDIT:** I believe I've figured it out! Feel free to take a look in case I've made a mistake.

**Problem:** Let $n$ and $d$ be positive integers and $m, b \in R$, some ring.  If $F(n) = \sum_{d|n}f(d)$ and $\sum_{d|n}g(d) = mF(n)+b$, then $g(n) = mf(n) + b \iota(n)$.

**Proof:**

$$\sum_{d|n}g(d) = mF(n)+b$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$g(n) = \sum_{d|n}\mu(d)(mF(\frac{n}{d})+b)=m\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)F(\frac{n}{d})+b\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)$$
But our other assumption is, $F(n) = \sum_{d|n}f(d) \Rightarrow f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)F(\frac{n}{d})$.
Then,
$$m\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)F(\frac{n}{d})+b\sum_{d|n}\mu(d) = mf(n) + b\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$g(n) = mf(n) + b\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)$$

But $\iota (n) = 1$ if $n=1$ and $\iota (n) = 0$ if $n>1$, so $\iota(n)$ and $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)$ have the same property. So we conclude,
$$g(n) = mf(n) + b\iota(n)$$

Comment: what is $\iota (n)$?

Comment: It's 1 if n=1 and 0 otherwise

Comment: You seem to be in the right track. What happens if $\iota = \sum _{d|n} \mu (d)$? Can you show it?

Comment: I have answer explaining that and making the hint clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I will try to put you in the track:
You correctly have tried to use the Mobius inversion formula getting that
$$f(n)=\sum _{d|n}\mu (n/d)F(d),$$
so, if you try to compute $\sum _{d|n}\mu (n/d)(mF(d)+b),$ and you show that $\iota (n)=\sum _{d|n}\mu (d),$ **Hint:** Show it for a power of prime and use multiplicativity, then
$$\sum _{d|n}\mu (n/d)(mF(d)+b)=m\sum _{d|n}\mu (n/d)F(d)+\sum _{d|n}\mu (n/d)b=mf(n)+b\iota(n),$$
concluding, again by Mobius, that this is $g(n).$

Comment: Your comment was very helpful.. this is pretty much what I did and edited the post. I think I edited my post and you answered almost at the same time.

Comment: @Mobley Nicely done. We were writing at same time.